# How do you disconnect from a boost signal2 using a functor to a method of a class?

Tags: c++, boost, publish-subscribe

I am not getting the behavior I am expecting when disconnecting a slot (that is a class method) from from a boost::signals2.  My terminology is probably off, so I will provide a minimal working example (MWE) below demonstrating what I see and what I expect.  The short version is that I am disconnecting from the signal, but it is staying there.  Everything works great if I do this with a stand-alone function, it is when I use a class method that I run into this behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> `>> tree`

```
.
├── main.cpp
└── SConstruct

0 directories, 2 files
```

> `>> cat SConstruct`

```
Program('main.cpp')
```

> `>> cat main.cpp`

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
    void bar(int n) {
        std::cout << "Called foo::bar with " << n << std::endl;
    }
};
typedef boost::function<void(int)> Signal_f;
int main() {

    foo f;
    boost::signals2::signal< void(int) > my_signal;
    Signal_f functor = boost::bind(&foo::bar, f, _1);
    std::cout << "Created signal, and it has "
              << my_signal.num_slots() << " subscribers." << std::endl;
    my_signal.connect(functor);
    std::cout << "Subscribed to signal, and it has "
              << my_signal.num_slots() << " subsciber." << std::endl;
    my_signal(1);
    my_signal.disconnect(&functor);
    std::cout << "Un-Subscribed to signal, but it still has "
              << my_signal.num_slots()
              << " subsciber, and it should not have any now." << std::endl;
    my_signal(2);
    return 0;
}
```

> `>> scons`

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o
scons: done building targets.
```

> `>> ./main`

```
Created signal, and it has 0 subscribers.
Subscribed to signal, and it has 1 subsciber.
Called foo::bar with 1
Un-Subscribed to signal, but it still has 1 subsciber, and it should not have any now.
Called foo::bar with 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re-implementing using `scoped_connection`:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
    void bar(int n) {
        std::cout << "Called foo::bar with " << n << std::endl;
    }
};



typedef boost::function<void(int)> Signal_f;
int main() {

    using boost::signals2::scoped_connection;

    foo f;
    boost::signals2::signal< void(int) > my_signal;
    Signal_f functor = boost::bind(&foo::bar, f, _1);
    std::cout << "Created signal, and it has "
              << my_signal.num_slots() << " subscribers." << std::endl;

    // the scoped_connection object is RAII
    auto con = scoped_connection(my_signal.connect(functor));

    std::cout << "Subscribed to signal, and it has "
              << my_signal.num_slots() << " subsciber." << std::endl;
    my_signal(1);

    // disconnect the connection object, not the signal
    con.disconnect();
    std::cout << "Un-Subscribed to signal, and it now has "
              << my_signal.num_slots()
              << " subscibers." << std::endl;
    my_signal(2);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
Created signal, and it has 0 subscribers.
Subscribed to signal, and it has 1 subsciber.
Called foo::bar with 1
Un-Subscribed to signal, and it still has 0 subscibers.
```

Comment: I do like the scoped connections, but I was hoping to not have to manage another object in my full implementation.  The functor object already had to be created, and it would be ideal to use it to disconnect.  If no one else can provide direction on how to use the functor to disconnect, I'll accept this answer as "you can't do that, do this instead."

Comment: @KennethE.Bellock there's another option - signals2 gives you the opportunity to use `connect_extended` which causes a reference to the connection to be passed to the slot handler.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/signals2/example/extended_slot.cpp

Answer (score 1):

I do disconnect from a boost::signal2::signal using boost::signals2::connection object returned by connect method.

Comment: I prefer the scoped_connection that handles stuff automatically